# How do i pass function parameter as string in fish shell

Tags: shell-script, string, fish

Octave has an --eval option that takes a sting like "sqrt(4)" and outputs "ans = 2".
I want to create a function that passes the a parameter as string so i can call it like this:

```
calc sqrt(4)
```

echivalent to:

```
octave --eval "sqrt(4)"
```

I wrote a simple function like this:

```
function calc --wraps octave
   octave --eval "$argv"
end
```

It does not work.

OUTPUT:

```
$calc sqrt(4)
fish: Unknown command: 4
in command substitution
fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
calc sqrt(4)
```

Comment: "does not work" is a useless problem description: what _does_ happen?

Comment: I have posted the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are the fish syntax for [command substitution](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#command-substitution). You have no choice but to escape the parentheses or quote the argument:

```sh
calc sqrt\(4\)
calc 'sqrt(4)'
```

In a simple case like this, you might prefer an [abbreviation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#abbreviations):

```sh
abbr -a calc 'octave --eval'
```

Then when you type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, fish replaces that text with "octave --eval". (Still need to protect the parentheses in the argument though)

> Can I make abbr to add " " automatically. So when i type calc Space i will apear 'octave --eval " " ' and my cursor will be in the quotes?

No, but you can do this with a key binding and a `commandline` function.

```
function calc_binding
    commandline -r 'octave --eval ""'
    commandline -C (math (commandline -C) - 1)
end

# bind Alt+c to that function
bind \ec calc_binding
```

When you hit Alt-C, the current command line is replaced by `octave --eval ""` and the cursor is placed one character back, before the ending double quote.

See `bind --help` and `bind -a` to see the current key bindings: think of a key sequence that's memorable for you, and `bind -a` will show if it's available.

Comment: Can I make abbr to add " " automatically. So when i type calc Space i will appear as 'octave --eval " " ' and my cursor will be in between the quotes?

Comment: Like adding a LeftArrow: 0x1B so it moves one letter left?